# login problem in Ubuntu v 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login

My Ubuntu was working properly but today when i switch on the system and type my password then the screen started blinking and after some time a blue screen came and it remain their nothing else was coming. i have restarted 2 times but the same thing happens again can any one help me. 
i was using Ubuntu version 16.04

Comment: From the `grub` boot menu, select `advanced options` and choose an older kernel (not the first one) to boot with.

Comment: i am a beginner in ubuntu so can you please explain the thing . How to go to grub boot menu?